# Why a pointer to a structure is used in the polynomial add/mult sourcecode

Tags: c, arrays

```
/* Program to multiply two polynomials. */

/#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAX 10

struct term
{
 int coeff ;
 int exp ;
} ;

struct poly
{
 struct term t [10] ;
 int noofterms ;
} ;

void initpoly ( struct poly *) ;
void polyappend ( struct poly *, int, int ) ;
struct poly polyadd ( struct poly, struct poly ) ;
struct poly polymul ( struct poly, struct poly ) ;
void display ( struct poly ) ;

void main( )
{
 struct poly p1, p2, p3 ;

 clrscr( ) ;

 initpoly ( &p1 ) ;
 initpoly ( &p2 ) ;
 initpoly ( &p3 ) ;

 polyappend ( &p1, 1, 4 ) ;
 polyappend ( &p1, 2, 3 ) ;
 polyappend ( &p1, 2, 2 ) ;
 polyappend ( &p1, 2, 1 ) ;

 polyappend ( &p2, 2, 3 ) ;
 polyappend ( &p2, 3, 2 ) ;
 polyappend ( &p2, 4, 1 ) ;

 p3 = polymul ( p1, p2 ) ;

 printf ( "\nFirst polynomial:\n" ) ;
 display ( p1 ) ;

 printf ( "\n\nSecond polynomial:\n" ) ;
 display ( p2 ) ;

 printf ( "\n\nResultant polynomial:\n" ) ;
 display ( p3 ) ;

 getch( ) ;
}

/* initializes elements of struct poly */
void initpoly ( struct poly *p )
{
 int i ;
 p -> noofterms = 0 ;
 for ( i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++ )
 {
  p -> t[i].coeff = 0 ;
  p -> t[i].exp = 0 ;
 }
}

/* adds the term of polynomial to the array t */
void polyappend ( struct poly *p, int c, int e )
{
 p -> t[p -> noofterms].coeff = c ;
 p -> t[p -> noofterms].exp =  e ;
 ( p -> noofterms ) ++ ;
}

/* displays the polynomial equation */
void display ( struct poly p )
{
 int flag = 0, i ;
 for ( i = 0 ; i < p.noofterms ; i++ )
 {
  if ( p.t[i].exp != 0 )
   printf ( "%d x^%d + ", p.t[i].coeff, p.t[i].exp ) ;
  else
  {
   printf ( "%d", p.t[i].coeff ) ;
   flag = 1 ;
  }
 }
 if ( !flag )
  printf ( "\b\b  " ) ;

}
/* adds two polynomials p1 and p2 */
struct poly polyadd ( struct poly p1, struct poly p2 )
{
 int i, j, c ;
 struct poly p3 ;
 initpoly ( &p3 ) ;

 if ( p1.noofterms > p2.noofterms )
  c = p1.noofterms ;
 else
  c = p2.noofterms ;

 for ( i = 0, j = 0 ; i <= c ; p3.noofterms++ )
 {
  if ( p1.t[i].coeff == 0 && p2.t[j].coeff == 0 )
   break ;
  if ( p1.t[i].exp >= p2.t[j].exp )
  {
   if ( p1.t[i].exp == p2.t[j].exp )
   {
    p3.t[p3.noofterms].coeff = p1.t[i].coeff + p2.t[j].coeff ;
    p3.t[p3.noofterms].exp = p1.t[i].exp ;
    i++ ;
    j++ ;
   }
   else
   {
    p3.t[p3.noofterms].coeff = p1.t[i].coeff ;
    p3.t[p3.noofterms].exp = p1.t[i].exp ;
    i++ ;
   }
  }
  else
  {
   p3.t[p3.noofterms].coeff = p2.t[j].coeff ;
   p3.t[p3.noofterms].exp = p2.t[j].exp ;
   j++ ;
  }
 }
 return p3 ;
}

/* multiplies two polynomials p1 and p2 */
struct poly polymul ( struct poly p1, struct poly p2 )
{
 int coeff, exp ;
 struct poly temp, p3 ;

 initpoly ( &temp ) ;
 initpoly ( &p3 ) ;

 if ( p1.noofterms != 0 && p2.noofterms != 0 )
 {
  int i ;
  for ( i = 0 ; i < p1.noofterms ; i++ )
  {
   int j ;

   struct poly p ;
   initpoly ( &p ) ;

   for ( j = 0 ; j < p2.noofterms ; j++ )
   {
    coeff = p1.t[i].coeff * p2.t[j].coeff ;
    exp = p1.t[i].exp + p2.t[j].exp ;
    polyappend ( &p, coeff, exp ) ;
   }

   if ( i != 0 )
   {
    p3 = polyadd ( temp, p ) ;
    temp = p3  ;
   }
   else
    temp = p ;
  }
 }
 return p3 ;
}
```

In this code I am having some problems :

1. what is the purpose of using the member variable "noofterms"
2. In the functions void initpoly ( struct poly *), void polyappend ( struct poly *, int, int ) the polynmials are taken as a pointer to a structure type.but in case of functions struct poly polyadd ( struct poly, struct poly ),struct poly polymul ( struct poly, struct poly ),void display ( struct poly ) simple structure variable are used.

Can someone kindly explain me the reason...

Comment: Yeah, I have an answer that I'll finish.  But then I'll delete it until you accept answers to your other questions.  BTW, you can find links to the other questions you've asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/415041/tuhin

Comment: @Omnifarious: I will keep that in mind...Sorry for my conduct !

Comment: @Omnifarious Although I agree with your sentiment, I'm not sure that bribing the poster with answers is really the best approach.

Comment: By the way I always found it a cleaner design to do 

    struct poly * initpoly ();

, and allocate memory in initpoly, also providing a `freepoly(struct poly *)` function to deallocate it. Not really an answer but just a remark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions that take a pointer as their argument thereby can alter the original object. If you pass a simple structure variable, it is copied and the function can only alter the copy.

And noofterms counts the number of terms the polynomial is made up from.

Answer (score 0):

`noofterms` is used so that other routines know how many of the array elements are relevant.  It is not strictly necessary as a coefficient of `0` would be sufficient, but it can make calculations slightly more efficient by avoiding doing anything with elements that have a coefficient of `0`.

If you think about it, all the functions that take a `struct poly *` argument modify the thing that's passed in.  That's why they need a pointer.  If they took a `struct poly` and modified that, you wouldn't see the modifications in the rest of your program.